# Why react doesn't render whitespaces

Tags: reactjs, whitespace

I have the following example:

```
<h1>{errors.email?.message || ' '}</h1>
```

Which means: If there is an error message, display it, else display a normal space.
The problem I faced is that react shows the error if it's available, else it doesn't show anything, in other words, the space string is always ignored and will be never displayed.

Why is this happening and how can I show a string that contains only a whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be able to display only whitespace by using the `white-space` property:

```js
function App() {
    return <h1 style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>{" "}</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
h1 { /* so we can see the h1 */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what does `whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"` mean?

Comment: @arrmani88 It's a CSS property that preserves whitespace in the element. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp8h5ma7/) for an example. I have a space in the h1 but I need to preserve it in order for it to be displayed. Whitespace in elements is usually ignored unless it's between text.

Answer (score 0):

For a ternary in react use : instead of ||. That way it will use the empty string if nothing is in the error message. Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ogae42?file=src/App.js) simple stack on how that is either shown or not based on a state object.

Edit: For optional chaining your logic should be working fine. We might need more data though. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kqwxbx?file=src/App.js) you can see that the white space is showing on the first one. The second one doesn't include a white space.

What does `errors.email?.message` print to the console?

Comment: I think OP is using the optional chaining operator instead of ternary https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I might need more info then. What do you mean you want to show a string with only whitespace? You aren't going to "see" whitespace unless there is something right next to the h1. Check my edit to see if that answers your question. Can you include a bit more code?

Comment: I have a form, under each `<input />` I should show either an error msg, or the same space as the error msg. Otherwise, if I don't show the white space, that area that's occupied by the error message will be hidden, so if the user did an invalid input, the space between the `<input />` will grow, which doesn't look good